# PHP passthru execution status

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to use the PHP passthru function to execute an OS command on Linux.

I am using it as follows. The Linux command is just to list files in a directory I know does not exist and then I am just echoing the status to make sure it's not 0.

```
$osexec = "ls /tp";
$status = 0;

$result = passthru($osexec, $status);

echo $status;
```

However the status seems to be the entire output of the command including the status number

```
ls: /tp: No such file or directory
2
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing `stderr` plus the `$status` value. To hide `stderr` you could do the following:

```
// 2> /dev/null to hide stderr
$osexec = "ls /tp 2> /dev/null";
$status = 0;

$result = passthru($osexec, $status);

echo $status;
```

Comment: thank you, I didn't realise it includes the entire output intentionally

Answer (score 0):

passthru automatically outputs all the output from your command.

try `echo "-------\n".$status;` and you should see that there is just some mixed up output from different sources (passthru / echo).